# different ways to ignore a signal?

Tags: c, linux, signals

Im' new to Linux and signal handling.
the `signal` function prototype is

```
sighandler_t signal(int signum, sighandler_t handler);
```

below is my questions:

Q1-if I want to ignore `SIGINT` signal, then I just need to simply code as:
`signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);`, is my understanding corrct?

Q2-What if I code as:

```
void sigint_handler(int sig) 
{
   //do thing
}

int main() 
{
    /* Install the SIGINT handler */         
    if (signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler) == SIG_ERR)  
       unix_error("signal error");                
    
    pause(); /* Wait for the receipt of a signal */  
    
    return 0;
}
```

since my own `sigint_handler` does nothing, it is pretty much like ignoring the `SIGINT`, so can I say this approach is fundamentally the same as `signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);`?

Q3-where does the `SIG_IGN` locate? Is it in the `.code` segment in the user's process address space as:
[image]

if my assumption is correct,  does the compiler automacially inject this handler into the compiled code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *if I want to ignore `SIGINT` signal, then I just need to simply code as: `signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);`, is my understanding corrct?*

Yes, but the docs for `signal` recommend using `sigaction`. `signal`'s semantics vary by system, while `sigaction`'s are more consistent.

> *does the compiler automacially inject this handler into the compiled code?*

No. The compiler doesn't create an empty handler for `SIG_IGN`. It literally tells the OS to ignore the signal for the process. It's not a function pointer but a value `signal` treats specially.

> *since my own `sigint_handler` does nothing, it is pretty much like ignoring the `SIGINT`, so can I say this approach is fundamentally the same as `signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);`?*

While both effectively ignore the signal, there are differences.

- When using a signal handler, a blocking syscall might return prematurely with error `EINTR` to allow the signal handler to run. This won't happen with `SIG_IGN`.
- `SIG_IGN` will survive `exec`, but a handler doesn't.
- On some systems, the signals's disposition is reset to `SIG_DFL` when the signal handler is called, so your code would only ignore the first instance of the signal on such systems.
- There are other differences, which may vary by platform.

Answer (score 1):

Q3. `SIG_DFL`, `SIG_IGN`, and `SIG_ERR` are not real functions. They are constants that `signal()` handles specially. On Linux specifically, `SIG_DFL` has integer value `1`, `SIG_IGN` has integer value `0`, and `SIG_ERR` has integer value `-1`, none of which are valid function pointers.

Q2. No, a custom signal handler (even if no-op) has slightly different behavior than `SIG_IGN`. If you call `exec()`, signals with disposition `SIG_IGN` will be inherited, while all other signals will be reset to `SIG_DFL` (with the exception of `SIGCHLD`, where POSIX does not specify should be `SIG_IGN` or `SIG_DFL`).

Q1. Yes, but even though it doesn't matter for *this* case, it is preferred to use `sigaction()` over `signal()` in general.